# Python inheritance with dictionary mutation

Tags: python, inheritance, dictionary

I'm curious on how inheritance works in case of dictionary mutations, I always thought that with each new instance the inherited classes get recreated.

```
class A(object):
    test = {"B": 0}

    def change_test(self, index):
        self.test["B"] += index

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.change_test(self.index)
        super(A, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class B(A):
    index = 1
    def print_test(self):
        print self.test


class C(A):
    index = 2
    def print_test(self):
        print self.test

b = B()
b.print_test()

c = C()
c.print_test()
```

Why does this return {'B': 1} {'B': 3} and not {'B': 1} {'B': 2}?

Comment: test is actually a static variable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned the variable is created at `import`-time and not recreated. This variable will be shared and because `dict` (but also `list`, ...) is mutable also changed by all instances of this class. To workaround it create the variable at instance-creation time:

```
class A(object):

    def change_test(self, index):
        self.test["B"] += index

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.test = {"B": 0}          # Create it here!!!
        self.change_test(self.index)
        super(A, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Normally only immutable types (`int`, ...) are save to use it as class-variables.

---

See also:

- [The second example in this Python documentation section](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables)
- ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument) (because this behaviour also affects default arguments for functions)

Answer (score 3):

The class variable `test` is shared among instances of `A` and its children.

```
print A.test is B.test # True
print B.test is C.test # True
```

Initally, `test` is `{"B": 0}`.
When you initialize `b`, `change_test` from `A` is called because `B` inherits `__init__` from A. So now `test` is `{"B": 1}`. After that, you initialize `c`, which leads to another call to `change_test` with `index` 2. Now `test` is `{"B": 3}` because 1 + 2 = 3.

Comment: but why isn't this the case when A.test is an integer?

Comment: @spedy It works exactly the same way when `A.test` is an integer. It just does not have much consequences because integers are immutable anyway. But still, instances of `A`, `B`, and `C` would share the same integer object in memory.